# Using download.file gives old version of file

Tags: r, caching, download

I'm trying to download the latest version of a file that I download every month, but I can't seem to get download.file to retrieve the latest version.

I've tried using cacheOK=FALSE, but it doesn't seem to affect anything. Putting the same URL directly into a web browser gives the correct (latest) version of the file every time. Looking into the actually downloaded file confirms that R is getting an older version, whereas the browsers are not.

To simplify, I'm downloading a zip file with a csv inside, and reading the csv before processing:

```
report <- "MWTS"
url <- paste0("http://www.census.gov/econ_getzippedfile/?programCode=", report)
download.file(url, paste0(report, "-mf.zip"), mode="wb", cacheOK=FALSE)
file.raw <- readLines(unz(paste0(report, "-mf.zip"), paste0(report, "-mf.csv")))
```

As of this posting, `grep("^371", file.raw)` gives an integer of length 1, but it should give hundreds (371 is the timecode for November 2022, the latest data release).

Comment: How do you know that it has been updated on the website? https://www.census.gov/econ_getzippedfile/ reports "maintenance", so perhaps they haven't released the Nov 2022 data yet.

Comment: Not sure what the maintenance is about (hopefully it will magically fix this!), but the direct download URL https://www.census.gov/econ_getzippedfile/?programCode=MWTS still downloads the full up-to-date file. The same thing also happened with a file last month.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the remote site replies differently based on the presence of some fields, namely `User-Agent` and (seems odd to me) `Accept-Language` (perhaps to reduce international queries ??).

While this returns the previous data,

```r
library(httr)
res <- GET("https://www.census.gov/econ_getzippedfile/?programCode=MWTS")
writeBin(content(res), "MWTS-mf1.zip")
```

This returns the current data:

```r
res <- GET("https://www.census.gov/econ_getzippedfile/?programCode=MWTS",
           user_agent("''"), add_headers(`Accept-Language`="''"))
writeBin(content(res), "MWTS-mf2.zip")
file.info(Sys.glob("MWTS-mf*.zip"))
#                size isdir mode               mtime               ctime               atime exe
# MWTS-mf1.zip 528852 FALSE  666 2023-01-10 13:03:18 2023-01-10 13:03:07 2023-01-10 13:03:19  no
# MWTS-mf2.zip 518246 FALSE  666 2023-01-10 13:03:19 2023-01-10 13:03:19 2023-01-10 13:03:19  no
```

Note the change in file size. Some interesting points:

- Using `user_agent("")` still worked, but
- using `` add_headers(`Accept-Language`="") `` does *not* work.

I infer from this that they have some filters, perhaps *"non-empty accept-language, and a user-agent not known to be curl or similar"*.

Comment: CptnJustc, does this work for you?

Comment: It appears to work, thanks! However, now the old method seems to work as well. Will have to double-check next month what works immediately after the report's released. Will try to remember to update this then.